# How to find the count of distinct nodes between a single node of particular label to all other nodes in a different label in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have 4 different types of labels and multiple nodes in each. Let's say Node A of label P is connected to multiple nodes of label Q and those nodes are connected to multiple nodes of label R. Now I'm trying to figure out the count of distinct nodes in label R that is connected to Node A either directly or through label Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH path = (a:P)-[*1..2]->(r:R)
WHERE a.id = 'A' AND (LENGTH(path) = 1 OR 'Q' IN LABELS(NODES(path)[1]))
RETURN DISTINCT r
```

This simple example assumes a consistent "forward" relationship directionality for both relationships.

[ADDENDUM]

This should be a better query than that one asked about in the comments:

```
MATCH path = allShortestPaths((a:P)-[*1..2]->(r:R))
WHERE a.id = $resource_key AND (LENGTH(path) = 1 OR 'Q' IN LABELS(NODES(path)[1]))
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT r)
```

Comment: ```
MATCH (e:P { resource_key: '{resource_key}' }),(n:R), p = allShortestPaths((e)-[*]-(n))
RETURN count (distinct n)
```

I used this and this seem to work, do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: No, that is very inefficient. The `(n:R)` causes a cartesian product, and the `[*]` does not put an upper limit on the length of the path search -- so you query can take forever and/or run out of memory in a large DB. Also, you could find paths with none-`Q` nodes in the middle. See my addendum to my answer.